# jQuery $.get not returning 'each' in correct order?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a page with 8 'entries'. Each `.entry` has a link `fetchLink` and a title `entry-title`.

On the page `fetchLink` leads to, there is *another* link `fetchedInfo` that I want to `$.get` and use as the href to wrap `entry-title` with.

My code attempt:

```
    var fetchLink;      

    $(".entry").each(function() {

        fetchLink = $(this).find('a').attr('href');         
        
        $.get(fetchLink, function(res) {
           var fetchedInfo = ($(res).find(".g1-cta-button-wrap a").attr("href"));
           console.log(fetchedInfo);                
           $(".entry-title").wrap('<a href="' + fetchedInfo + '"></a>');                
        });

    });
```

Unexpected results:

1:
`console.log(fetchedInfo)` is showing the `fetchedInfo` links out of order-- aka, in a scrambled order instead of in the order the `entry`'s appear on the page.

2: Instead of wrapping each `entry-title`, it's just wrapping the FIRST one in a nest of all the hyperlinks retrieved by `get`. The other `entry-title`s remain unaffected.

I would really appreciate help with the logic here! I did not know dealing with $.get would be so confusing.

HTML https://jsfiddle.net/6zdp4uva/

```
<div class="entry">
   <header class="entry-header">
      <div class="entry-before-title">
         <p class="entry-meta entry-stats g1-meta g1-meta g1-current-background"><span class="entry-views "><strong>13</strong><span> Views</span></span><span class="entry-comments-link entry-comments-link-0"></span></p>
         <span class="entry-categories "><span class="entry-categories-inner"><span class="entry-categories-label">in</span> <a href="https://example.com/w/category/general" class="entry-category entry-category-item-1">general</a></span></span>            
      </div>
      <h3 class="g1-delta g1-delta-1st entry-title"><a href="https://example.com/w/general/Title/2309366202" rel="bookmark">Title</a></h3>
   </header>
   <div class="entry-summary">
      <p>description <a class="g1-link g1-link-more" href="https://example.com/w/general/Title/2309366202">More</a></p>
   </div>
   <footer>
      <p class="g1-meta entry-meta entry-byline entry-byline-s entry-byline-with-avatar">
         <span class="entry-author">
         <span class="entry-meta-label">by</span>
         <a href="https://example.com/members/admin/profile/home/" title="Posts by admin" rel="author">
         <img alt="" src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/9f221658beaba2ee853f978fa48f49c2?s=24&amp;r=g&amp;d=retro" srcset="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/9f221658beaba2ee853f978fa48f49c2?s=24&amp;r=g&amp;d=retro 2x" class="avatar avatar-24 photo" height="24" width="24">
         <strong>admin</strong>
         </a>
         </span>
         <time class="entry-date" datetime="2020-07-21T09:23:36+00:00" title="July 21, 2020, 9:23 am">about 15 hours ago</time>             <a href="https://example.com/w/general/Title/2309366202"><strong>0</strong> <span>Comments</span></a>
      </p>
   </footer>
</div>
```

note in my actual code I do:

```
fetchLink = $(this).find(".entry-comments-link").find('a').attr('href');
```

since the comments link is the one I need to use for the $.get

Comment: That is how asynchronous calls work

Comment: Providing your HTML structure would go a long way towards solving this

Comment: I added the actual HTML now. The only thing to note is that to simplify my question I had written `fetchLink = $(this).find('a').attr('href');` instead of what I actually have in my code, which is `fetchLink = $(this).find(".entry-comments-link").find('a').attr('href'); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't qualifying which `.entry-title` to wrap so it's wrapping **all of them** each time a GET request completes

> #### [.wrap()](https://api.jquery.com/wrap/)
>
> Wrap an HTML structure around **each element** in the set of matched elements

It's not clear because you have not provided any HTML but if each `.entry-title` exists within the `.entry` that you're iterating, try this

```js
$(".entry").each(function() {
  const entry = $(this)
  const fetchLink = entry.find('a').attr('href')
  const entryTitle = entry.find('.entry-title') // find .entry-title within this .entry

  $.get(fetchLink, res => {
    const href = $(res).find(".g1-cta-button-wrap a").attr("href")
    console.log(href)
    entryTitle.wrap($('<a>', { href }))
  }, 'html')
})
```

The console will log each HREF as the requests complete. This could happen in any order but at least now, you will only be changing the document within each `.entry`.

Answer (score 1):

The results are "out of order" because get is asynchronous. If the order the results are displayed in is important, you should not attempt to make another get until the previous one has been resolved. In your case, I don't think it's important. You should just expect to see the results show up as they arrive.

The reason only the first entry title is being wrapped is because that's what you're telling it to do. You need to create a reference to the current object being processed. So the first line in your jQuery each should be

```
const $this = $(this)
```

Then instead of

```
$(".entry-title").wrap('<a href="' + fetchedInfo + '"></a>')
```

you should do

```
$(this).find(".entry-title").wrap('<a href="' + fetchedInfo + '"></a>')
```

This will make jQuery only wrap the entry title of the currently processing entry.

Addendum to the first point: Each `get()` triggers a new request to some endpoint and consumes a segment of the server's bandwidth. You state in your question that you have 8 entries. This is on the upper end of the number of requests I would consider sending to my own server at once. It would be better to either configure your site so that you can retrieve all the information at once, or if you end up with many more than 8 entries or performance issues to create a queuing process to only request one thing at a time.

Comment: Be careful, within the `$.get` callback, `this` will no longer refer to the `.entry` element unless you change it to an arrow function

Comment: `In your case, I don't think it's important.` It is unfortunately very important. Is there a different method I can be using to get them retrieved in Order?